# Missing Preview and designer button with the iReport plugin in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ireport

I have created my first iReport jrxml file by using the iReport plugin in NetBeans but there is missing preview and designer button.

Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your designer preview is not available because the ireports netbeans plugin has not been added properly.

[you can download is here : http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport)

then go to netbeans -> tools -> plugins -> downloaded -> Add plugins...
and select the downloaded plugin and go through the wizard

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue.  I'm using **Netbeans 8.0.1** version and I firstly downloaded and installed **iReport 5.6** from sourceforge. But when I tried to create the report I also noticed that I 'm having only the xml. Preview and Design buttons were not there.

So then I remove the installed plugins (.nbm files) and downloaded [this](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport) from Netbeans and reinstalled the plugin.

Then it worked perfectly for me. So my thought is, your plugin might missing some files.. so better if you can remove that and re-download the plugin from [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preview the report then right click on 'opened tab' (example: if you want to see the preview of DayReport.jrxml then open it and right click on that tab) and select the editor menu, then you can preview, designer or see the xml of your report

Answer (score -1):

i have also faced that probleam , because i have netbeans 7.4 and my ireport plugin vergion was different , so i uninstall old plug in and  install same version of my netbeans 7.4 .. and now it is showing design , pervious etc

Comment: It's not clear from this answer whether it's the plugin you reinstalled or Netbeans itself.  Please [edit] this answer to clarify (and to fix the numerous spelling and grammatical errors).